# Is there a virtualization solution for OSX Lion that doesn't require JRE?

Tags: macos, virtualization, java, parallels, jre

I'm trying to verify if I can get along with using OSX Lion without JRE and the possibility to run virtual machines would be the last mile. VirtualBox is Java based so that's out of the question. Does Parallels require JRE? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not all software with ugly UI is Java-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox.

Despite coming from Snoracle, like Java, VirtualBox is not Java-based - it was written in C, C++ and occasional bits of assembly ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)). It does have a Java API, but that's entirely optional. Have you tried installing VirtualBox on your JRE-less Lion?

Comment: Interesting, didn't try but will do...

Answer (score 3):

VMWare Fusion is what I use at work (and at home, but rarely); no JRE required.

Parallels also doesn't require a JRE, and they've just released a new Lion-ized version.